# Can I give detailed status information to the Elastic Beanstalk load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, elastic-beanstalk

I am using a health-check URL to allow Elastic Beanstalk to poll the health of my instances. I would like traffic to be distributed according to some internal state of each instance. Currently I just return status 200.

Can I send detailed health information, e.g. a "health score" that the load-balancer will use to direct users more intelligently?

Comment: EBS is elastic block store, it doesn't poll anything. If you mean ELB you should update your question.

Comment: @Tim I do; fixed

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/386502/can-elastic-load-balancers-correctly-distribute-traffic-to-different-size-instan/386527#386527

Answer (score 0):

ELB attempts to route traffic to the least loaded server, but you cannot weight them. If you need that function you'll need to use a software load balancer, but ELB is probably going to be more reliable and scalable.

The AWS documentation is not very precise in this area.

Reference [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/386502/can-elastic-load-balancers-correctly-distribute-traffic-to-different-size-instan/386527#386527) which is fairly exhaustive.